# Do an A Record redirect like Tumblr's Custom Domain feature

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain, tumblr, a-records

I am wanting to make a site where users will get a subdomain such as.. user.website.com
However I would like to offer a service like Tumblr where they can get a domain from a host, say GoDaddy, and set their A Record to my server's IP and instead of when someone goes to user.website.com it goes to whatever domain they have pointing to my IP.. 
Can anyone please refer me to an article that tells how to do such a thing.. or give me some advice..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you'll do is setup a wildcard DNS record for your domain and from your httpd virtual host, you will have to configure the servername using the input of the user for their preferred name (and you'll have to be proficient in .htaccess manipulation to do that -- sorry, I am not so familiar with it too so I cannot offer an advice regarding that aspect.).

You might want to look at this blog post for more information on how it's roughly done http://ma.tt/2003/10/wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains/

Hope this helps.
Ismael Casimpan :)